# Removing mutability without losing speed

Tags: performance, kotlin, immutability

I have a function like this:

```
fun randomWalk(numSteps: Int): Int {
    var n = 0
    repeat(numSteps) { n += (-1 + 2 * Random.nextInt(2)) }
    return n.absoluteValue
}
```

This works fine, except that it uses a mutable variable, and I would like to make everything immutable when possible, for better safety and readability. So I came up with an equivalent version that doesn't use any mutable variables:

```
fun randomWalk_seq(numSteps: Int): Int =
    generateSequence(0) { it + (-1 + 2 * Random.nextInt(2)) }
        .elementAt(numSteps)
        .absoluteValue
```

This also works fine and produces the same results, but it takes 3 times longer.

I used the following way to measure it:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
fun main() {
    val numSamples = 100000
    val numSteps = 15708
    repeat(5) {
        val randomWalkSamples: IntArray
        val duration = measureTime {
            randomWalkSamples = IntArray(numSamples) { randomWalk(numSteps) }
        }
        println(duration)
    }
}
```

I know it's a bit hacky (I could have used JMH but this is just a quick test - at least I know that `measureTime` uses a monotonic clock). The results for the iterative (mutable) version:

```
2.965358406s
2.560777033s
2.554363661s
2.564279403s
2.608323586s
```

As expected, the first line shows it took a bit longer on the first run due to the warming up of the JIT, but the next 4 lines have fairly small variation.

After replacing `randomWalk` with `randomWalk_seq`:

```
6.636866719s
6.980840906s
6.993998111s
6.994038706s
7.018054467s
```

Somewhat surprisingly, I don't see any warmup time - the first line is always lesser duration than the following 4 lines, every time I run this. And also, every time I run it, the duration keeps increasing, with line 5 always being the greatest duration.

Can someone explain the findings, and also is there any way of making this function not use any mutable variables but still have performance that is close to the mutable version?

Comment: You can write it with tail recursion instead of a loop and not mutate `n` and annotate it with `tailrec` though I doubt that's actually clearer code. Other than that I doubt you'll get reliably to the performance of a regular loop - and if you will it will _probably_ be too easy to break by another programmer to be worth it.

Comment: Your sequence code isn't doing the same thing is it? All values are tossed except the last. Your imperative code is adding all results together. I think `.elementAt(numSteps)` should be replaced with `.take(numSteps).sum()`.

Comment: Does rewriting the imperative version really give much more safety and reliability? From what I've seen, the consensus in object-functional languages seems to be that while there are often clear benefits from using a functional approach at the large scale, once you get down to the internals of small functions there's much less to be gained, and it's often outweighed by the extra performance (and conciseness) of imperative code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is slower for two main reasons: boxing and the complexity of the iterator used by `generateSequence()`'s Sequence implementation.

Boxing happens because a Sequence uses its types generically, so it cannot use primitive 32-bit Ints directly, but must wrap them in classes and unwrap them when retrieving the items.

You can see the complexity of the iterator by Ctrl+clicking the `generateSequence` function to view the source code.

@Михаил Нафталь's suggestion is faster because it avoids the complex iterator of the sequence, but it still has boxing.

I tried writing an overload of `sumOf` that uses IntProgression directly instead of `Iterable<T>`, so it won't use boxing, and that resulted in equivalent performance to your imperative code with the `var`. As you can see, it's inline and when put together with the `{ -1 + 2 * Random.nextInt(2) }` lambda suggested by @Михаил Нафталь, then the resulting compiled code will be equivalent to your imperative code.

```
inline fun IntProgression.sumOf(selector: (Int) -> Int): Int {
    var sum: Int = 0.toInt()
    for (element in this) {
        sum += selector(element)
    }
    return sum
}
```

Ultimately, I don't think you're buying yourself much in the way of code clarity by removing a single `var` in such a small function. I would say the sequence code is arguably harder to read. `var`s may add to code complexity in complex algorithms, but I don't think they do in such simple algorithms, especially when there's only one of them and it's local to the function.

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent immutable one-liner is:

```kotlin
fun randomWalk2(numSteps: Int) = 
    (1..numSteps).sumOf { -1 + 2 * Random.nextInt(2) }.absoluteValue
```

Probably, even more performant would be to replace

[image]

with

[image]

so that you'll have one multiplication and n additions instead of n multiplications and (2*n-1) additions:

```kotlin
fun randomWalk3(numSteps: Int) = 
    (-numSteps + 2 * (1..numSteps).sumOf { Random.nextInt(2) }).absoluteValue
```

**Update**

As @Tenfour04 noted, there is no specific stdlib implementation for `IntProgression.sumOf`, so it's resolved to `Iterable<T>.sumOf`, which will add unnecessary overhead for `int` boxing.
So, it's better to use `IntArray` here instead of `IntProgression`:

```kotlin
fun randomWalk4(numSteps: Int) = 
    (-numSteps + 2 * IntArray(numSteps).sumOf { Random.nextInt(2) }).absoluteValue
```

Still encourage you to check this all with JMH

Comment: With JMH, OP's imperative is ~51K ops/s, both of yours are ~35K ops/s, and OP's sequence is ~15K ops/s (and 12K if the functionality is fixed as I commented above). I suppose yours is slower than imperative because of the boxing, and the Sequence is slower yet because of the complexity of its iterator.

Comment: If I replace `sumOf` with an overload that operates on IntProgression so there's no boxing, the range solution is equivalent in performance with imperative code, and your `randomWalk3` is slightly better.

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting that the last solution in your answer allocates an IntArray full of zeros, whose elements are not used at all, and only the array's size is of any importance. You might as well just use ByteArray, no? (In fact, I've just seen a significant speed increase by using ByteArray instead of IntArray.)

Comment: @k314159 You've seen it in JMH test? Indeed, you may use an array of any primitives here instead of `IntArray`. Yes, with `ByteArray` you will have a better memory footprint (`BooleanArray` would be the best in this regard), but I don't expect any performance boost from this change.

Answer (score 0):

I think:**"Removing mutability without losing speed"** is wrong title .because
mutability thing comes to deal with the flow that program want to achieve .
you are using var inside function.... and 100% this var will not ever change from outside this function and that is mutability concept.
if we git rid off from var everywhere why we need it in programming ?